# Copy jpa entity source from one maven module to other module during compilation

Tags: spring, jpa, maven-3, jpa-2.0

I have developed multi module spring + jpa + maven application , below is structure

```
parentFolder
child-module1(which only contains jpa entity classes )
----pom.xml
child-module2(this module uses 'child-module1' entity classes and init database with sample data)
----pom.xml
child-module3(which deals with frontend)
pom.xml
```

I am facing issue with `child-module2` , which is spring based java app and uses `child-module1` entity classes. when i run `child-module2` Main.java it throws exception **`"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Account is not mapped [from Account a where a.name=:name]"`**

if i copy same source code which we have in 'child-module1' in `child-module2` with same package structure than it works fine, my moto is to reuse `child-module1` across all modules. not sure what i am missing or do i need to add some plugin so it can work.

I think issue is that as `child-module2` is a java app and generates jar which don't have `jpa` entity so it throws such exception , if source of `jpa` entity can in place it can work but not sure how ?

Comment: Are you using maven `parent-child relationship`?

Comment: i am just reusing resources from one maven module to other

Comment: How you are reusing it?

Comment: i am reusing child-module1 in other modules as a dependency , for example i am using child-module1 in child-module2 but as i said it is throwing exception.